# Iterating through an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am taking a Perl tutorial and are somewhat stumped on how to iterate through an array when calling a library

The library should contain a function that takes in an array of numbers (of arbitrary size). The function will then calculate the average of the numbers, the total of all of the numbers added together, and a new array of numbers which is comprised of the original input numbers each divided by 2. It will then return a new list with all of that information.

The script file,  should get a list of numbers from the user  via STDIN, call the library function and print the returned numbers.

So far I have this in the main script:

```
  #!/usr/local/bin/perl

  require 'test4lib.pl';

  my @numbers;

  while (<>) {
      s/\s+\z//;
      last if $_ eq "";
      push @numbers, $_;
  }
  print "My Numbers are:  @numbers\n";
  number_crunch(@numbers);

  print "Total is: $total\n";
  print "Average is: $Average\n";
  print "Divided by 2 is: @divided_by\n";
```

and this in the library function:

```
  sub number_crunch {
    foreach $number(@_) {
      $total = $sum+=$_ for (@_);
      $count = $numelements=(@_);

      $Average = ($total / $count);
      print "Total is: $total\n";
      $Average = ($total / $count);
      print "Average is: $Average\n";

      @divided_by = ();
      foreach (@_) {
        $new_number = $_ / 2;
        push @divided_by, $new_number;
      }
    }
  }
  1;
```

The issue is that the function in the library is only grabbing the first number of the array and I'm unsure how to iterate through the array.  Any help appreciated.

Becky

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. The standard advice for perl is to `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that. You iterate through all passed numbers, passing the current one into `$number` but never use that variable, you then try to calculate the `$total` of all numbers within that loop but for that you use something called `$sum` which you never set, you calculate `$average` twice for every number (as you are still in the loop) and so on... You need to take a step back and think about the flow of your sub before rewriting it. And yes, never write a perl script without `strict` and `warnings` until you really know what you do. I'd say not even then, but thats me.

Answer (score 0):

As i explained in my comment your code has other issues but let me still answer your question of how one can pass an array into a subroutine properly.

Your way of just using the array as argument and directly accessing `@_` does in fact work, as long as you only want to pass a single array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 3);

foo(@array);

sub foo
{
    foreach my $num (@_)
    {
        print "$num\n";
    }
}
```

However, what actually happens here is that your array is turned into a list and passed and the contents of that list are stored in `@_`. That quickly becomes a problem if you want to pass two arrays of unknown length that you need to distinguish in your sub as all their elements will just follow each other in `@_`.

The better practice when passing arrays (or hashes or anything really) to subs is using references:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 3);

foo(\@array);

sub foo
{
    my @passedArray = @{$_[0]}; #Interpret the reference passed to us first as an array
    foreach my $num (@passedArray)
    {
        print "$num\n";
    }
}
```

In this case i copy the array as the first thing in the sub. I did this here to make it slightly more readable but it also serves a safety purpose. As this is passing by reference, if you were to directly work on `@{$_[0]}` and changed it, those changes would also show up in `@array` outside of the sub. Of course, in many cases, that is exactly what one wants. Compare:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, 3);

square(\@array);

foreach my $num (@array)
{
    print "$num\n";
}

sub square
{
    foreach my $num (@{$_[0]})
    {
        $num *= $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage people to call subroutines using '&'. It hasn't been necessary for twenty years and it can potentially have confusing side effects.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to not produce a warning". There are no circumstances where `foo()` produces a warning but `&foo()` doesn't. `&` is simply unnecessary when calling a subroutine, so it becomes pointless punctuation that just confuses programmers who haven't seen it before. Prototypes have nothing to do with it. Most subroutines should not have prototypes. The "potentially confusing" side effects are when you call `&foo` (which, to most people's eyes is not so different to `&foo()`) and Perl passes `foo` the current value of `@_` rather than an empty array.

Comment: Oh. I see that you have a) removed the comment that I just replied to and b) removed the ampersands. Thank you.

Comment: @DaveCross There are a lot of things one can do that are not necessary. I admit, in this case, the code is cleaner without the empty prototype and the ampersand, overriding it. Answering your answer to my deleted answer (this is probably a great idea ^^): The ampersand suppresses prototype checking. So it has everything to do with prototypes. And as such it also suppresses prototype-checking warnings (as for example a lack of forward declaration produces). However yes, in this case there is no reason for a prototype and no reason for an ampersand, hence i removed my comment. ^^

Comment: Oh, I know that `&` suppresses prototype checks. But if you're using prototypes then you shouldn't suppress them. And if you're not using them, there's no need to suppress them. In short I can't think of any circumstance where using the ampersand is either necessary or leads to cleaner code. See my comment on [this blog post](http://neilb.org/2014/06/03/learning-perl.html) for a more detailed exposition of my thoughts on the subject (which I should turn into a blog post at some point).